# What is the correct way to test performance of methods?

Tags: c#, performance, data, validation

I made a few classes for processing and validating data in xlsx and csv.

However, I am curious in testing how fast the methods I wrote in C# for the heavy lifting are.

Here's what I currently am thinking of (written in C#):

```
// use this to test the performance of the method on files with various sizes

class FileProcessorPerformance
{
    private static Stopwatch sw;
    public static Stopwatch PerformanceSpeedStart()
    {
        sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        return sw;
    }

    public static void PerformanceSpeedEnd(Stopwatch stopwatch)
    {
        stopwatch.Stop();
        TimeSpan ts = stopwatch.Elapsed;
        string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds / 10);
        Console.WriteLine("Run Time: " + elapsedTime);
    }
}
```

An usage example would be like:

```
Stopwatch sw = PerformanceSpeedStart()
ProcessData();
PerformanceSPeedEnd(sw);
```

Besides using logic such as time complexity (big-O), how do people benchmark their solutions, if they do at all?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `Stopwatch.StartNew()` to create a running stopwatch object.

Comment: Just run it in a loop a million times and stopwatch it. Seconds = microseconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a single simple method, using a stopwatch can work well.  For larger, more intricate code, though, what you want is a *profiler*, an external tool that attaches to your program as a debugger, lets you run it, and monitors how long the code that you're executing takes and where the time is being spent.

When you're finished, it gives you a statistical report explaining where you're spending most of your time, which you can generally drill-down into to get a more detailed look at it.  Profilers can take a bit of work to understand how to use them, but they're extremely powerful for performance tuning once you've learned.

Comment: So I wrote a lot of isolated private methods to be make it cleaner and easier to debug, and I'm calling a lot of these methods inside a public method.

I think in the end, there will be a WCF service that I'll be working with that will use this and apparently WCF have timeouts, so I'm thinking ahead of myself to figure out a way to pinpoint where most of the time was spent on which method if I need to optimize the performance of my code.

So it seems like a profiler is the way to go here?

Comment: @ygongdev Yeah.  For C#, I'd recommend dotTrace from JetBrains.

Comment: will dotTrace work with VS2015 since I'm not using any IDEs from JetBrains?

Comment: @ygongdev Yes.  It can be run as its own program, independent of the IDE, or it can integrate with Visual Studio.